# Google Places API no Longer Returns Picture Links for Radius Searches, Only RankBy Distance?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I am seeing a recent change to the Google Places API where, when I run a query like so, I get photos.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34.1686107,-83.9003022&rankby=distance&types=bakery|food|cafe|restaurant&key=xyz

When I run one like so, I no longer get photos.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34.203979,-83.943787&radius=2000&types=bakery|food|cafe|restaurant&key=xyz

Is anyone else seeing this issue? The only difference is the radius vs. rankby argument. I used to see the photos for both queries.

Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely happening, but only by radius and it's only recently.  I've tried to reach google about this bug, but I've gotten no response [I just tried about an hour ago]